# Unit testing Collection in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have a unit test that will allow me to iterate through a Collection object containing a list of vehicle. Upon each iteration, I want to check to see if the vehicle is an instance of automobile. So my code looks a bit like this:

```
public class VehicleChecker {
    protected boolean checkVehicles(Garage garage) {
        for (Vehicle vehicle : garage.getVehicles() {
            if (vehicle instanceof Automobile) return true;
        }
    }
}
```

So I wrote my code accordingly:

```
@Mock private Garage mockGarage;
@Mock private VehicleCollection mockVehicleCollection;
@Mock private VehicleCollectionIterator mockVehicleCollectionIterator;
@Mock private Vehicle mockVehicle;

@Test
public void testCheckVehicles() {

    VehicleChecker testObject = new vehicleChecker();

    when(mockGarage.getVehicles()).thenReturn(mockVehicleCollection);
    when(mockVehicleCollection.iterator()).thenReturn(mockVehicleCollectionIterator);
    when(mockVehicleCollectionIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
    when(mockVehicleCollectionIterator.next()).thenReturn(mockVehicle);

    boolean result = testObject.checkVehicles(mockGarage);

    verify(mockGarage).getVehicles();
}
```

The problem occurs with the verify statement. Based on how it was written, the test should pass. When I step through the code, however, I the code just skips the for loop entirely. Why is that? Is there a difference in the way one iterates through a Collection as opposed to an ArrayList? If so, how do I properly mock that interaction?

Comment: Two questions: Why are you manually checking the type? That's usually a bad design. And why mock the collection instead of just feeding it a real one?

Comment: I'm struggling with a particular version of this code that has no return type and accepts no arguments. That includes the Collection. The best I can do is mock the collection by proxy. Suffice to say, I am unable to feed an actual Collection object.

Comment: Just tried the whole thing, works as expected, inlcuding that the test fails because you mock a `Vehicle` and not an `Automobile`. Ok, two little typos, but nothing that the IDE will not highlight. So, strange, if it doesn't run for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have initialized mocks with MockitoAnnotations.initMocks?

Comment: I put the Assert mostly out of habit. I'll be sure to edit that out, though.  As for the verify, I know I've initialized all the mock objects that I need. Besides, doesn't the @Mock annotation achieve the same effect as Mockito.initmocks?

Comment: Had wrong name in original answer. The method is MockitoAnnotations.initMocks. And yes it must be called, from the Javadoc: "Initializes objects annotated with Mock-annotation for given testClass.".

Comment: I didn't use the Mockitoannotation.initMocks method, but `@RunWith( MockitoJUnitRunner )` instead, which also worked.

Comment: Yes, that is another way to initialize your mocks.